# Bodiless function in Golang

Tags: function, go

Reading the source code of [`math/floor.go`, starting from line 13](http://golang.org/src/math/floor.go#L13), I read some code like this:

```
func Floor(x float64) float64

func floor(x float64) float64 {
    if x == 0 || IsNaN(x) || IsInf(x, 0) {
        return x
    }
    if x < 0 {
        d, fract := Modf(-x)
        if fract != 0.0 {
            d = d + 1
        }
        return -d
    }
    d, _ := Modf(x)
    return d
}
```

It seems the `func Floor` has no body. I tried to copy and paste these code in my go file. it doesn't compile. The error message is `missing function body`. So my question is: is a bodiless function legal in Go's syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the way how functions are implemented in assembly. You find the assembly implementation in the `floor_ARCH.s` (e.g.: [AMD64](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/math/floor_amd64.s#L10)) files.

To quote the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations):

> A function declaration may omit the body. Such a declaration provides the signature for a function implemented outside Go, such as an assembly routine.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `floor(x ...)` (lower case) function implementation then?  How does it relate to the assembly implementation?

Comment: @maerics I believe that's a fallback Go implementation, used for example by [floor_arm.s](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/math/floor_arm.s#L8). Such things could possibly also be done for reference or for use in tests to check other implementations against. (Go itself implies no relation whatsoever between `Floor` and `floor` indentifiers).

Comment: @DaveC Thanks for the quote. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had "../../../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20190814235402-ea4142463bf3/go/ssa/interp/testdata/src/fmt/fmt.go:3:6: `missing function body`" error!

and it was because I used fmt without importing it so my IDE imported the wrong package.

I fixed it by removing the import (`golang.org/x/tools/go/ssa/interp/testdata/src/fmt`)

and just importing `fmt`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue.